# fetch all the data from main table and all the corresponding child record with activeYn != N., using spring jpa

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Trying to achieve**

fetch all the data from main table and all the corresponding child record with activeYn != N.

This is parent entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR")
public class IncidentHdr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="IR_SEQ_INCIDENT_ID",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="INCIDENT_ID")
    private long incidentId;

    @Column(name="PATIENT_ID")
    private Long patientId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  mappedBy="incidentHdr")
    private Set<Attachments> attachments;
    ....

    //other child entities

}
```

This is the child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="IR_TB_ATTACHMENTS")
public class Attachments implements Serializable {

    private Long attachmentId;
    private IncidentHdr incidentHdr;
    private boolean activeYn;
}
```

Here we are genegating the custom query, we are appending only one condition here.

```
public IncidentHdr findIncidentDetailForId(Long incidentId) throws BusinessException {
        StringBuilder query = null;
        IncidentHdr incidentHdr = null;
        StringBuilder incidentDetailQuery = null;
        Query q = null;
        Map < String, Object > parameters = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
        List < String > criteria = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {

            incidentDetailQuery = new StringBuilder();
            query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append(ReposJPQL.GET_INCIDENTS_DETAIL);

            criteria.add("inc.incidentId = :incidentId ");
            parameters.put("incidentId", incidentId);


            if (criteria.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < criteria.size(); i++) {
                    incidentDetailQuery.append(" AND ");
                    incidentDetailQuery.append(criteria.get(i));
                }
            }

            query.append(incidentDetailQuery);
            q = em.createQuery(query.toString());

            for (Entry < String, Object > entry: parameters.entrySet()) {
                q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

            incidentHdr = (IncidentHdr) q.getSingleResult();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | DataAccessException | EntityNotFoundException  e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
        return incidentHdr;
    }
```

ReposJPQL, Here defined the query with activeYn condition.

```
public interface ReposJPQL {
        public String GET_INCIDENTS_DETAIL = "SELECT inc "
            + " FROM IncidentHdr inc left join inc.attachments att WHERE att.activeYn <> 'N' ";
    }
```

Even though the records are present it return  "org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query"
error

**Or is there any other way to achieve this ? @Where(clause=...) option is pure hibernate so cant use that.**

Comment: please check my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606934/spring-boot-json-serialize-custom-object-with-array-of-custom-objects/47608556#47608556

Comment: The exception pretty clearly states that your query returns no rows. Next step would be to show: what data gets inserted into the database and what exact query with which parameter values you execute.